# Multihreading recursive program c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, recursion, parallel-processing

I am working on a recursive algorithm which we want to parallelize to improve the performance.

I implemented multithreading using Visual c++ 12.0 and < thread > library . However I dont see any performance improvements. The time taken either less by a few milliseconds or is more than the time with single thread.

Kindly let me know if am doing something wrong and what corrections should I make to the code.

Here is my code

```
void nonRecursiveFoo(<className> &data, int first, int last)
{

    //process the data between first and last index and set its value to true based on some condition
    //no threads are created here
}


void recursiveFoo(<className> &data, int first, int last)
{

    int partitionIndex = -1;
    data[first]=true;
    data[last]=true;
    for (int i = first + 1; i < last; i++)
    {
        //some logic setting the index 
        If ( some condition is true)
            partitionIndex = i;
    }

//no dependency of partitions on one another and so can be parallelized
    if( partitionIndex != -1)
    {
        data[partitionIndex]=true;

        //assume some threadlimit
        if (Commons::GetCurrentThreadCount() < Commons::GetThreadLimit())
        {

            std::thread t1(recursiveFoo, std::ref(data), first, index);
            Commons::IncrementCurrentThreadCount();
            recursiveFoo(data, partitionIndex , last);
            t1.join();
        }
        else
        {
            nonRecursiveFoo(data, first, partitionIndex );
            nonRecursiveFoo(data, partitionIndex , last);
        }

    }
}
```

//main

```
int main()
{
    recursiveFoo(data,0,data.size-1);
}
```

//commons

```
std::mutex threadCountMutex;
static void Commons::IncrementCurrentThreadCount()
{
    threadCountMutex.lock();
        CurrentThreadCount++;
    threadCountMutex.unlock();
}

static int GetCurrentThreadCount()
{
    return CurrentThreadCount;
}
static void SetThreadLimit(int count)
{
    ThreadLimit = count;
}
static int GetThreadLimit()
{
    return ThreadLimit;
}
static int GetMinPointsPerThread()
{
    return MinimumPointsPerThread;
}
```

Comment: Does this code compile and work? If so you should try posting this over on the codereview site: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You shouldn't rely on reading threads seeing updates to `CurrentThreadCount` when they're not locking their read access; using an atomic_int would be preferable.  Anyway, I suggest you add some logging to show you how the threads are actually dividing the work.  Whether it can be expected to be faster also depends on the amount of data you're processing: too little and the overheads of thread creation will dwarf the benefits.  As is, if your partitioning doesn't divide the work evenly, you may end up with some very short-running threads while 1 or 2 end up doing most work synchronously.

Comment: Just because you have threaded your code doesn't mean it is faster. What have done in the way of profiling your single threaded code?

Comment: This can have various reasons, but first of all: how lonc does thd program rougvmy run? How  many data Items do you have? How many cores do you have? What is your thread count limit?

Comment: And what compiler do you use?

Comment: And how large is `data.size-1`?

Answer (score 0):

Without further information (see comments) this is mostly guesswork, but there are a few things you should watch out for:

- First of all, make sure that your partitioning logic is very short and fast compared to the processing. Otherwise, you are just creating more work than you gain processing power.
- Make sure, there is enough work to begin with or the speedup might be not enough to pay for the additional overhead of thread creation.
- Check that your work gets evenly distributed among the different threads and don't spawn more threads than you have cores on your computer (print the number of total threads at the end - don't rely on your `ThreadLimit`).
- Don't let your partitions get too small, (especially no less than 64 Bytes) or you end up with false sharing.
- It would be MUCH more efficient, to implement `CurrentThreadCount` as a `std::atomic<int>` in which case you don't need a mutex.
- Put the increment of the counter before the creation of the thread. Otherwise, the newly created thread might read the counter before it is incremented and spawn a new thread again, even if the max number of threads is already reached (This is still not a perfect solution, but I would only invest more time on this if you have verified, that overcommitting is your actual problem)
- If you really must use a mutex (for reasons outside of the example code)  you have to use it for every access to `CurrentThreadCount` (read and write access). Otherwise this is - strictly speaking - a race condition and thus UB.

Answer (score 0):

By using `t1.join` you're basically waiting for the other thread to finish - i.e. not doing anything in parallel.

By looking at your algorithm I don't see how it can be parallelized(thus improved) by using threads - you have to wait for a single recursive call to end.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not doing anything in parallel, as every thread creation blocks, until the created thread has finished. Hence, your multithreaded code will always be slower than the non multithreaded version.

In order to parallelize you could spawn threads for that part, where the non-recursive function is called, put the thread ID into a vector and join on the highest level of the recursion, by walking through the vector. (Although there are more elegant ways to do that, but for a first should this would be OK, I think).

Thus, all non recursive calls will run in parallel. But you should use another condition than the max number of threads, but the size of the problem, e.g. `last-first<threshold`.